# How do I avoid freezing UI in Android when Inserting into SQLite DB in Intent Service?

Tags: android, sqlite, intentservice

I am inserting a large number of items(~200) into an SQLite DB in an intent service's onHandleIntent in an android application, but the UI freezes and I get an Application Not Responding. To the best of my knowledge, an IntentService's onHandleIntent runs in a worker thread, so I don't understand why this is happening. How do I avoid this?
Btw, the application works fine when adding a few items(~5)

Comment: Same problem facing.My app hangs untill all items are downloaded & saved in DB

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use transactions for optimization.

Help link:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_transactions.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AsyncTask Class. Developer Docs are [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)